# Enable link markdown to work in room descriptions

Tags: feature-request, chat, markdown, hyperlinks

**Please enable link markdown in room descriptions.** Currently links in room descriptions just appear as plaintext. So when I tried to add a reference to site rules at the end of a chat room's description, like so —

> [Be Nice](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) applies here.

It instead appeared in plain text:

> [Be Nice](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) applies here.

So I had to write this instead:

> Be Nice applies here: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice

That's workable, but the first option would be preferable, especially if we're linking to multiple places.